# ¿Como hago para que se deslice hacia la izquierda la foto al hacer click?

Tags: html, jquery

Estoy usando jQuery y he probado esto:

```
            $("#ilussion").click(function(){
                $("#ilussion").animate({direction:'left'},500);
            });
```

```css
   .headerEnd{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:#000000;
    height:100px;
    text-align: center;
   }
   #fotoEndi{
    margin-left: 100px;
   }
   
   @font-face{
    font-family: "TituloEndi";
    src: url("GameofBrush.ttf");
   }
   a:link{
    text-decoration:none;
    
   }
   a:visited{
    color: #000000;
   }
   
   #nombreEndi{
    text-align: center;
    margin:0 auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    color: #8B0000; 
    font-family: "TituloEndi";
    font-size:40px;
   }
   
   .header{
    height:50px; width:100%;
    text-align:center;
   }
   
   .menu{
    height: 37px;
    width:100%;
    background-color: #B22222; 
    color:#333; 
    text-align:center;
    box-shadow:0px 4px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0)
   }
   .wrapper{ height:2000px; 
      width:100%; 
      padding-top:20px
   }
   .menu-fixed {
    position:fixed;
    z-index:1000;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #999;
   }
   ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block; 
    font-size: 25px;
    width: 100%;
   }
   
   body{
    background-color: #DCDCDC;
    margin: 0;
   }

   #menu li{
    background: #DCDCDC;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    background-color:#B22222;
   }
   
   .listaArriba{
    color:  #000000;
    width: 150px;
   }
   
   #titulua{
        background-color:#000;
     text-align:center;
     margin-left: 300px;
     margin-top: 7px;
   }
   
   .lyrics{
    background-color: white;
    height: 650px;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    top: calc(50% - 225px);
    left: calc(50% - 380px);
    display-inline: block;
   
   }
   
   #footer{
    margin-top:0px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color:#B22222;
   }
   
   #soundcloud{
    margin-right:40px;
    margin-top: 3px;
   }
   .navigationFoot{
    text-align: right;
   }
   a{
    color:black;
    text-decoration:none;
   }
   #o{
    margin-left: 250px;
    float: top;
   }
   .nav-pills>li.active>a,
   .nav-pills>li.active>a:focus,
   .nav-pills>li.active>a:hover {
      background-color: #B22222;
   }
   
   #singles,#albums{
    text-align: center;

   }
   
   #div_negro{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    z-index: 9000;
    display: none;
   }
   
   #float{
    width: 700px;
    height: 0px;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position:fixed;
    top: calc(50% - 300px);
    left: calc(50% - 330px);
    z-index: 9000;
    text-align: center;
   }
   h3{
    font-size: 42px;
   }
   #divSK{
    float: left;
    margin-left: 70px;
    margin-top: 40px;
   }
   #divWA{
    float: right;
    margin-right: 70px;
    margin-top: 40px;
   }
   
   #ilussion{
    margin-top: 40px;
   }
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <header class="headerEnd">
   <div class = "cabecera">
    <ul id = "lista1">
     <a href="home.html" id="fotoEndi"><img src="endikasangroniz.png" id=titulua></a>
     <a href="../EndiIngles/endi.html" id = "o"><img src="../Bandera/uk.png"></a>
     <a href="../EndiCastellano/endi.html"><img src="../Bandera/banderaEspana.png"></a>
     <a href="../EndiEuskera/endi.html"><img src="../Bandera/ikurrina.png"></a>
     
    </ul>
   </div>
  </header>
  <header class = "header">
   <div class="menu" id="menu">
    <nav class="top-menu">
     <ul class = "navigation">
      <li class="listaArriba" id="news"><a href="news.html">NEWS</a></li>
      <li class="listaArriba" id="conciertos"><a href="gigs.html">GIGS</a></li>
      <li class="listaArriba" id="videos"><a href="videos.html">VIDEOS</a></li>
      <li class="listaArriba" id="songs"><a href="music.html">MUSIC</a></li>
      <li class="listaArriba" id="lyrics"><a href="lyrics.html">LYRICS</a></li>
      <li class="listaArriba" id="store"><a href="https://endikasangroniz.bandcamp.com/" target="_blank">STORE</a></li>
     </ul>
    </nav>
   </div>
  </header>
   <div id="float" style="overflow:scroll">
    
   </div>
   <div class="lyrics">
    <!-- Centered Pills -->
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
      <li class="active" id="albumPill"><a href="#">Albums</a></li>
      <li id="singlePill""><a href="#">Singles</a></li>
    </ul>
    
    <div id="albums">
     <img width="500" height="500" id="ilussion" src="https://forums.crackberry.com/attachments/blackberry-q10-f272/171886d1371181552t-bbm-display-picture-limitations-423341110329_qy737vid_l.jpg"></img>
    </div>
    
    <div id="singles">
      <div id="divSK">
       <img width="500" height="500" id="stolenK" src="../CaratulasAlbum/stolenKiss.jpg"></img>
      </div>
      <div id="divWA"> 
       <img width="500" height="500" id="wander" src="../CaratulasAlbum/wandering.png"></img>
      </div>
    </div><br><br>
   </div>
   <div id="footer">
     <ul class = "navigationFoot">
      <a id="n" href="https://es-es.facebook.com/EndikaSangroniz/" target="_blank"><img src="../IconosRedes/iconoFacebook.png" ></a>
      <a id="n" href="https://www.instagram.com/endikasangroniz/?hl=es" target="_blank"><img src="../IconosRedes/iconoInsta.png"></a>
      <a id="n" href="https://endikasangroniz.bandcamp.com/" target="_blank"><img id="soundcloud" src="../IconosRedes/bandcamp.png"></a>
     </ul>

   </div>
```

No he conseguido que funcione y no he encontrado nada que haga lo que quiero. He probado varias soluciones sacadas de Stack Overflow en inglés pero no he conseguido nada.
Saludos.

Comment: Podés probar de poner dentro de la función "onClick", cambiar la propiedad CSS del elemento $('illusion'), que corresponde al margen, con el valor que te parezca, y a esto mismo ponerle la animación. $('#ilussion').css('margin-left', '0px').animate('slow');

Comment: En tu línea `<li id="singlePill""><a href="#">Singles</a></li>` tienes unas comillas dobles ( " )  de más. Debe quedar `<li id="singlePill"><a href="#">Singles</a></li>`

Comment: El problema es que tengo todo el div centrado porque me interesa que esté de esa manera, así que no me valdría eso. Me gustaría saber si existe algún tipo de funcion que lo haga.

Comment: @FelipeM no me había fijado, ahora lo cambio

Comment: @TheWoodStudio No ha funcionado

Comment: Prueba quitando el tag de cierre `</img>`. El tag `<img>` no lo necesita pues es un elemento vacío. Aquí te dejo la referencia en la documentación de mozilla https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/img

Para que sepas que es un elemento vacío mira https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Empty_element

Comment: Ese no es el problema pero lo cambiaré

Comment: Te arroja algún error la consola del navegador?

Comment: No, no arroja ninguno